# Are there any other implementations of java.text.DateFormat apart from java.text.SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java, simpledateformat, java-6, date-format

java.text.SimpleDateFormat is after all an implementation of java.text.DateFormat. This implementation of DateFormat can understand the following pattern letters

```
G Era designator
y Year
M Month in year
w Week in year
W Week in month
D Day in year
d Day in month
F Day of week in month
E Day in week
a Am/pm marker
H Hour in day (0-23)
k Hour in day (1-24)
K Hour in am/pm (0-11)
h Hour in am/pm (1-12)
m Minute in hour
s Second in minute
S Millisecond
z Time zone
Z Time zone
```

Are there any other implementations of java.text.DateFormat, which can understand some other pattern letter group? If any, please let me know.

Comment: I imagine that you could roll your own using the DateFormat class.

Comment: `Apache commons` has a `FastDateFormat` implementation. Though it is not descendent of jdk `DateFormat`, but, it has a similar functionality and is Thread safe. (http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/time/FastDateFormat.html)

Answer (score 2):

`java.text.SimpleDateFormat` is the only publically-exposed JDK class that extends `java.text.DateFormat`; however, there is no guarantee that `DateFormat`'s factory methods, such as `getDateInstance()`, will necessarily return a `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`. They could instead return an instance of some other class provided by the JDK implementation. (Even in that case, I'm not sure that the other class would "understand some other pattern letter group", as you suggest; rather, I would *guess* this would be more likely to happen if the locale has date-parsing and –formatting needs that are more complex that what simple text patterns can provide, rather than that the locale needs *different* patterns. But who knows?)

As [the Javadoc for `java.text.DateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html) puts it:

> If you want even more control over the format or parsing, (or want to give your users more control), you can try casting the `DateFormat` you get from the factory methods to a `SimpleDateFormat`. This will work for the majority of countries; just remember to put it in a `try` block in case you encounter an unusual one.

And you can extend `DateFormat` with your own date-formatting subclasses, if you want. Its constructor is `protected`, not package-private, so you can subclass it freely.

Answer (score 0):

There is a replacement class available for `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` in [IBM's ICU project](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4j48rc1/com/ibm/icu/text/SimpleDateFormat.html). You can have a look at that. But this is just a replacement class and have nothing to do with `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` class.

Comment: I use my own subclass of java.text.DateFormat that delegates to ICU. You get the best of both worlds.